# Cannot deserialize instance of <Object> out of START_ARRAY token - webClient

Tags: reactive-programming, webclient, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am writing a simple `get` method using webclient to fetch property information. But then, I am getting below's error response message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-25T06:57:03.487+0000",
    "path": "/modernmsg/getentity",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.reputation.api.modernmsg.model.Entity` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.reputation.api.modernmsg.model.Entity` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]"
}
```

Actual json response is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Point Breeze",
        "street": "488 Lemont Dr",
        "city": "Nashville",
        "state": "TN",
        "postal_code": "37216",
        "slug": "point-breeze"
    }
]
```

Below is the method in my controller class to fetch property:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getentity")
    public Mono<Entity> getEntity(@RequestParam("token") String token, @RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return service.fetchEntity(token, name);
    }
```

And my fetchEntity method is:

```
public Mono<Entity> fetchEntity(String token, String name) {
        String url = host + version + entityEndpoint + "?token=" + token + "&name=" + name;
        return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToMono(Entity.class);
    }
```

Below is my Entity model:

```
package com.reputation.api.modernmsg.model;

import java.util.List;

public class Entity {

    private List<ModernMsgEntity> modernMsgEntity;

    public List<ModernMsgEntity> getModernMsgEntity() {
        return modernMsgEntity;
    }

    public void setModernMsgEntity(List<ModernMsgEntity> modernMsgEntity) {
        this.modernMsgEntity = modernMsgEntity;
    }
}
```

ModernMsgEntity model is:

```
package com.reputation.api.modernmsg.model;

public class ModernMsgEntity {
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postal_code;
    private String slug;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a JSON deserialization problem. Looking at your entity class, you're setting things up to expect a JSON response like:

```
{
"modernMsgEntity": [
    {
        "name": "Point Breeze",
        "street": "488 Lemont Dr",
        "city": "Nashville",
        "state": "TN",
        "postal_code": "37216",
        "slug": "point-breeze"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want Jackson to deserialize an array of objects directly, you have to tell it so:

```
Flux<ModernMsgEntity> messages = webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToFlux(ModernMsgEntity.class);
```

Comment: I tried with ```return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToFlux(ModernMsgEntity[].class);``` but it still throws the same error 


`JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of ModernMsgEntity[] out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of ModernMsgEntity[] out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]`

Comment: It's not the same error, your question mentions an error with `START_ARRAY token`, which is in line with the JSON body you're showing. Are you sure you're getting the right response?

Comment: Yes, the response is correct. Its an array of object.

Comment: You can try and take WebFlux out of the equation by directly using the response body as a String a deserialize it with an ObjectMapper instance with the `readValue` method.

Comment: I tried with by returning `Mono<ModernMsgEntity[]>` instead of `Flux<ModernMsgEntity[]>`, which worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189002/discussion-between-theone1one-and-brian-clozel).